# In R, assigning a number to a date, where the number corresponds to the nth rolling, non-overlapping period in a year that the date is included in

Tags: r

I need to calculate rolling but non-overlapping 7-day means in a huge dataset so that I can calculate the number of 7-day mean exceedences (means above a certain threshold) for each station.  The dataset looks something like this:

```
STATION  DATE         VALUE
A   1/15/2010   4
A   1/18/2010   5
A   1/25/2011   2
A   1/30/2011   1
A   2/2/2011    14
B   5/6/2012    6
B   5/14/2012   4
B   5/17/2012   3
B   1/29/2013   16
```

I want it to look like this:

```
STATION DATE         VALUE  7DAYPERIOD  YEAR-7DAYPERIOD
A   1/15/2010   4   1   2010-1
A   1/18/2010   5   1   2010-1
A   1/25/2011   2   1   2011-1
A   1/30/2011   1   1   2011-1
A   2/2/2011    14  2   2011-2
B   5/6/2012    6   1   2012-1
B   5/14/2012   4   2   2012-2
B   5/17/2012   3   2   2012-2
B   1/29/2013   16  1   2013-1
```

where the "7DAYPERIOD" corresponds to the nth non-overlapping 7-day period relative to the earliest date in a year for a station.  I was then going to concatenate the year with this number ("YEAR-7DAYPERIOD") and then aggregate by this identifier and station to calculate the means for each station.

I initially thought that lubridate "week" would help me out with this.  But "week" gives a number relative to January 1st.  I need the number to be relative to the earliest date in the year that is represented in the dataset AND have it be specific for a station.

Comment: Can you confirm what should happen at year boundaries? If a 7-day period would be cut short by the end of the year, should you a) cut it so the last period has fewer than 7 days, b) include days from the next year to make a whole 7 day period, c) extend the last period of the year to be longer than 7 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reproduces your example, but you don't have any cases dealing with year boundaries. We can do integer division with `%/%` to count the number of whole 7 day periods since the first date in a year. Implicitly, because we `group_by` both `STATION` and `YEAR`, this will cut short any 7 day period that crosses the end of the year (which can have ramifications if you are aggregating these values).

```r
library(tidyverse)

library(lubridate)
tbl <- read_table2(
"STATION  DATE         VALUE
A   1/15/2010   4
A   1/18/2010   5
A   1/25/2011   2
A   1/30/2011   1
A   2/2/2011    14
B   5/6/2012    6
B   5/14/2012   4
B   5/17/2012   3
B   1/29/2013   16"
)
tbl %>%
  mutate(
    DATE = mdy(DATE),
    YEAR = year(DATE)
  ) %>%
  group_by(STATION, YEAR) %>%
  mutate(
    `7DAYPERIOD` = as.integer(DATE - first(DATE)) %/% 7 + 1,
    `YEAR-7DAYPERIOD` = str_c(YEAR, "-", `7DAYPERIOD`)
  )
#> # A tibble: 9 x 6
#> # Groups:   STATION, YEAR [4]
#>   STATION DATE       VALUE  YEAR `7DAYPERIOD` `YEAR-7DAYPERIOD`
#>   <chr>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>            
#> 1 A       2010-01-15     4  2010            1 2010-1           
#> 2 A       2010-01-18     5  2010            1 2010-1           
#> 3 A       2011-01-25     2  2011            1 2011-1           
#> 4 A       2011-01-30     1  2011            1 2011-1           
#> 5 A       2011-02-02    14  2011            2 2011-2           
#> 6 B       2012-05-06     6  2012            1 2012-1           
#> 7 B       2012-05-14     4  2012            2 2012-2           
#> 8 B       2012-05-17     3  2012            2 2012-2           
#> 9 B       2013-01-29    16  2013            1 2013-1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You know what? I didn't even think about the boundaries! This worked great. Thanks, Calum You!

Comment: Just be careful when you use these numbers, the boundary issue means you cannot do things like `group_by(\`7DAYPERIOD\`) %>% mutate(avg = sum(VALUE)/7)` to get a per-day figure, for example.